# UPS for Raspberry Pi, but as a single PCB

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, ups

I'm building something which requires a system that would act as a UPS for a Raspberry Pi. In the system, the power might get abruptly for 2-3 seconds. I don't want the Pi to shut down or reboot then. So, ideally there should be a system that can provide a couple secs of backup power. If the power doesn't return within 5 secs, it should alert the Pi via a GPIO pin (which I'll handle with software to make it shutdown). After a successful shutdown, the next time power returns, the system should power on as normal. I can't afford to keep a power bank in this scenario as the power bank won't be able to completely shut down the Pi, and I won't be able to make the Pi automatically start up when the system is powered on later.

I found [this project](https://hackaday.io/project/25107-single-supercapacitor-ups-for-raspberry-pi/details) on hackaday.io which seems to suit my requirements.
But, I have some doubts regarding it. First of all, will I be able to print this into a PCB? I mean, are all the components in here readily available?

[image: Latest circuit diagram from article]

Also, the author says this is the latest working circuit.

1. With this circuit, imagine the input power gets cut and returns after a few seconds. In this scenario, I would want the system to resume operation as though nothing happened. As per my understanding, if the RPi doesn't pull the SHUTDN pin to LOW, this should work as expected. Am I right?
2. The official Raspberry Pi docs rate the RPi 4 Model B at an input rating of 5V/3A. This article mentions that even with two supercapacitors, the board would only supply 2.5A under a power failure scenario.. Is this OK?
3. With this setup, would the Pi normally get a supply of 5V/3A or would this board only provide 2.5A?

I'm really stuck with this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why couldn't a PCB be made? ... check suppliers for the parts availability

Comment: If you have never built a switch mode power supply and have to ask these questions I suggest you look for a ready made device. Building these is an art.

Comment: This is an electronics question - not a Pi question.

Comment: @Milliways I tried looking for readymade devices, but couldn't find any. If you have any suggestions, please post them.